# REACT useReducer is altering the state four times instead of once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, react-hooks

I am building an application of a coffee delivery with cart, payment form and history of orders. The problem I'm having is in the history. When I complete the order I need to gather the information of the cart items and the form to show it in the history. But my code is creating four equal orders when the function to add information to the orders array is triggered.

I´m using useReducer to alter the state of the orders array:

```
const reducer = (state: any, action: Actions) => {
    if (action.type === 'COMPLETE_ORDER') {
        const newOrdersList: OrderType[] = state.orders
        newOrdersList.push({
            orderItems: action.payload.orderItems,
            paymentPreference: action.payload.paymentPreference,
            totalPrice: action.payload.totalPrice,
            date: action.payload.date,
            id: action.payload.id
        })

        console.log(newOrdersList) // (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] 
        return {
            orders: newOrdersList,
            cartItems: []
        }
    }  
    return state
};

const [ orderState, dispatch ] = useReducer(reducer, {
    cartItems: [],
    orders: []
});

const completeOrder = (newOrderData: OrderType) => {
    dispatch({
        type: 'COMPLETE_ORDER',
        payload: {
            ...newOrderData
        }
    })
};
```

```
useEffect(() => {
    const totalPrice = cartItems.reduce(
        (total, currentValue) => total = total + currentValue.price!, 0
    )

    const orderItems = cartItems

    const newOrderData: OrderType = {
        orderItems,
        paymentPreference,
        totalPrice,
        date: format(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy', { locale: ptBR }),
        id: uuid()
    }
    
    completeOrder(newOrderData) 
}, []);
```

Why are four equal orders being added at once? And how can I fix it?

Comment: could you share a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (including the cardItems and types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are doing some things wrong in your reducer

1. you should spread the old state in your return to make sure you get the whole old state back
2. while adding a new object to an array it is wise to spread it first and filter out for potential duplicates
3. add the new payload to your state

Try using the following reducer

```
const reducer = (state: any, action: Actions) => {
  if (action.type === "COMPLETE_ORDER") {
    return {
      ...state, // 1
      orders: [
        ...state.orders.filter((order) => order.id !== action.payload.id), // 2
        action.payload, // 3
      ],
      cartItems: [],
    };
  }
  return state;
};
```

a deeper dive into this can be found at [medium](https://medium.com/swlh/few-ways-to-update-a-state-array-in-redux-reducer-f2621ae8061)